# C programming: Best data structure for this situation

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct

[image]

I have to make a dynamic structure for the image above. The image represents a warehouse, with 4 corridors each one with 3 shelves. Inside the shelves theres a small amount of products (P1 P3, P5, etc) and the respective quantity of each one.

I was wondering if you can help me choose the best and simplest solution for this problem.
Maybe a bi-dimensional array of pointers to an array of structures? or Linked lists?

Comment: are the number of shelves, corridors and products always within a certain range?

Comment: hey. The corridors and shelves have a fixed number. But the products inside a shelve can vary.

Comment: I'd rather use linked lists, but that's my personal opinion.

Comment: Use any of them.  What problem are you actually having?

Comment: What operations do you need to support? How will this data be mutated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct {
  char* product_name;
  int quantity;
} product_s;

struct {
  char* shelf_name;
  int num_products;
  struct product_s *products;
} shelf_s;

typdef struct {
  int corridor;
  int num_shelf;
  struct *shelf_s;
} corridor_t;
```

This would store your information.

Next:

```
#define NUMBER XXX
corridor_t *corridor = (corridor_t*)malloc(sizeof(*corridor) * NUMBER);
```

Usage is clear?

Comment: Thanks. Really bad mistake. xD